# Allow a page to be edited by a specific custom role

Tags: plugins, pages, user-roles, members

I have created multiple custom roles using the members plugin by Justin Tadlock.

Now i want certain pages to only be editable by the custom roles i select for them.

Is there a plugin i can use for that functionality or is that something i would have to code myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer looks like it will do the trick, or at least get you on the right path: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/259982/2807

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it already.

I used the ACF User role selector to select roles per page.
Then i made a checker for every page that matches the current logged in role with the role selected on the page.